# Don't mind the attitude of the protagonist of this riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Find me on a compass, lamers.
>   I have shown the way for gamers.
>   My neighbors describe this site.
>   Tell me, stranger, who am I?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are

> W
>
>   *Find me on a compass, lamers.*
>   W is for West
>
>
>   *I have shown the way for gamers.*
>   W is for moving forward in 'WASD' controls
>
>
>   *My neighbors describe this site.*
>   a: <strike>I guess this is a reference to the alphabet, the neighbours are U and V, hence 'double-U'</strike>
>  b: <strike>This is another reference to the first line, where "this site" is *SE*, also the neighboring points to *W* on the compass.</strike> (Thanks Lolgast, not sure if this is what you meant)
>  c:  The keys on a Qwerty keyboard that directly touch W are QASE, for Question and Answer, Stack Exchange. (suggested by VotBear)

Comment: For the neighbours line, I'm almost positive it should be FR (using rot13).

Comment: Oh I get it now

Comment: (Hmmm, E isn't strictly W's neighbour on the compass. I thought that SE referred to the keys next to W on a keyboard. But I guess the compass interpretation is valid, too.)

Comment: Yeah I couldn't quite match it with the compass perfectly either, but it's way too good a match for the second part of the sentence to be incorrect if you ask me.

Comment: @MOehm good point, the keyboard fits more literally

Comment: (Rot13) Va gur xrlobneq, j'f pybfrfg arvtuobef vapyhqr dn, dhrfgvbaf/nafjref, nf jryy nf fr, fgnpxrkpunatr. Rvgure bs gurfr pbhyq or jung gur evqqyr zrnag

Comment: @VotBear Oh wow, that's genius. Hadn't even thought of that.

Comment: @Jay yeah, that's what I meant, although it was not a perfect fit and Votbears solution is much better.

Comment: I am astonished. Well done!